# Why doesn't @contenteditable work on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, safari, contenteditable, mobile-safari

[Safari HTML Reference: Supported Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html) says:

> contenteditable
>
> If true, the element can be edited on
>   the fly; if false, it cannot.
>
> Availability
>
> Available in Safari 1.2 and later.
>   Available in iPhone OS 1.0 and later.

However, on my iPhone, I can't get it to work. Anyone have success with this?

You can try it with [this document](http://dev.plutext.org/sandbox/StyleResolutionTest.html) (admittedly not pure html, but that document works in desktop Safari, and Chrome and Firefox 3). I haven't been able to get even the simplest html document to be editable in mobile Safari.

Comment: I don't think you'll get an answer for this since it would require insight from someone at apple. You could also file a bug: https://bugreport.apple.com

Maybe you could rephrase the question to what you need to accomplish so we could come up with alternatives?

Comment: I wondered why Google Spreadsheet editing on iPhone OS was the way it is.  Now it makes sense: click the Edit link, little boxes open up for each cell on the row, fill in the numbers, click "submit," click "refresh."  It's doing a little <FORM>.

Comment: i don't have os4 beta 2 on my iphone but on the os4 beta 2 emulator it's still business as usual (doesn't work)...  please post a video..  i'd kill to see this working because it's the only thing stopping me from claiming iphone/ipad compatibility for my web app.

Comment: contenteditable absolutely does not work on the iphone or ipad..  still.

Comment: contenteditable still does not work on ios 4.1 or 4.2 gold master.

Comment: i can confirm contenteditable still doesn't work with ios 4.3

Comment: Noooooo! What about the HTML5 History API - when you go here http://balupton.com/sandbox/history.js/demo and add a few states do the back and forward buttons of safari work? Thanks btw :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`contenteditable` has been added to iOS 5 beta 2, according to one of the developer videos from WWDC 2011. I suggest signing up to Apple's [Safari developer program](http://developer.apple.com/safari) and downloading that video from the WWDC videos page.

If you sign up to be a Safari dev, you also gain the privilege to submit your Website to their online iOS Web app gallery.

**Edit:** I've confirmed this works on my iPad running iOS 5.0.1. Try it out here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand/

Comment: Thanks for this; I'll accept this as the answer as soon as someone playing with the beta can confirm it is real.

Comment: It must be real as CKEditor has added support for iOS5: http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_3.6.2_released

Comment: yes, iOS5 does support contenteditable. anything lower, does not.

Answer (score 2):

It works, kind of. I thought contenteditable doesn't work on iPhone before. When I set a div to contenteditable I couldn't move the cursor/pointer to where I wanted to move it. But, when I was fiddling around XHTML with contentEditable within iBooks.app on iPad, I found that "execCommand('insertText', null, 'foobar');" worked within Mobile Safari.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to, you could make a virtual keyboard using
clever css and javascript, and make it into a bookmarklet.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot focus the contenteditable element try adding this to your css

```
[contenteditable] {
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The design mode and content editable are working fine in IOS 5.But in previous versions it is not working.There is post

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/safari-5_html5/

Answer (score -3):

I think this is because editing HTML requires quite an advanced user interface. That's why desktop Safari implements it, while Mobile Safari doesn't.

Comment: This is an excuse, not an answer. In desktop Safari, you don't get any fancy controls, just the ability to type into an element. Surely, iPhone can support that.