# designMode or contentEditable on mobile safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, safari, mobile-safari

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't @contenteditable work on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723592/why-doesnt-contenteditable-work-on-the-iphone)

I'm trying to make an iframe editable in mobile safari. Works fine in all browsers (including safari) with both contentEditable and designMode=on, but on mobile safari i can't get any of them working.

Is there a way to make it work on mobile safari?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723592/why-doesnt-contenteditable-work-on-the-iphone

Comment: If you think your own question is a duplicate, just delete it.