# show iphone keyboard on html5 canvas with hidden textarea

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, canvas, keyboard

We´re using a (yui) canvas that represents the text in a textarea. 
Works fine in a browser, but on the iphone and ipad the keyboard does not show up, probably because there is no textarea. Is there a way to trigger the iphone to show the keyboard and treat the canvas as an input field?

thanks,

```
<canvas style="border: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 255); vertical-align: middle; cursor: text; padding: 0px;" width="31" height="23"></canvas>
<textarea id="f1" cols="80" rows="10"> </textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar questions have gone over this, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609765/manually-triggering-the-iphone-ipad-ipod-keyboard-from-javascript). It *seems* that it can't be done.

You might as well try a few things though: It's worth trying `.focus()` to see if that does anything, or maybe having some of your code trigger a `.focus()` for a hidden text area.