# Forcing the keyboard to appear in a mobile device in a website with no inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing this site that takes a keyboard input and processes it as it is being typed with no use of forms or inputs, I am calling a function with a keypress event.

I tried to test in my mobile device and oh, surprise! the keyboard doesn't show if there's no input field!

How can I force the keyboard to show up with Javascript if there are no input fields?

Thank you!

Comment: What about hidden inputs?

Comment: I thought about it, but.. is there a way to do it without using hidden inputs?

Comment: What's wrong with hidden inputs? Focus the input and you can capture events just like that. It's not really any different from listening for key events on the document - it's just that the document is always focused.

Comment: have you considered that maybe that's not very user-friendly for a mobile version. Maybe you should consider capturing the input some other way on mobile.

Comment: It's an experimental website... using inputs just doesn't fit in the design. But hidden inputs could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer is of help to you: [Manually triggering the iPhone/iPad/iPod keyboard from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609765/manually-triggering-the-iphone-ipad-ipod-keyboard-from-javascript)

Since you're mentioning calling a function with a keypress event

```
<input type='text' id='foo'><div onclick='$("#foo").focus();'>click</div>
```