# Ionic iOS Keyboard show issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iphone, ionic-framework, mobile-safari

HTML:

```
<ion-view ng-controller="EntryController" class="bg-grey">
   <ion-content scroll="true" overflow-scroll="true" class="start-page has-footer" has-bouncing="false">
       <div>  
          <input id="txtEntryInput" type="number" inputmode="decimal" pattern="[0-9]*" ng-model="entryInput" ng- 
          enter="someActionOnEnter()" />
       </div>
   </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

JS:

```
app.controller("EntryController", function($scope, $timeout, $http){

   //this binds the event when *Done* is pressed on keyboard mobile iOS browser
   $timeout(function(){
      var entryElement = document.getElementById('txtEntryInput');
      if(entryElement) {
        entryElement.addEventListener('focusout', function (e) {
           $scope.someActionOnEnter();
        });
      }
   });


   $scope.someActionOnEnter = function(){
       //some ajax call dummy
       $http({}).then(function(){
           //this is not focusing on element and not showing keyboard on mobile safari, on android it is working
           $timeout(function(){ 
               $('#txtEntryInput').focus()
           });     
       });
   };
   
});
```

I want to show the keyboard right after entry in the input. Its not working on browser.

In ionic app, i am using following configuration:

config.xml

```
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
```

ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 from https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard.git

And to show keyboard i am using following code:

```
$timeout(function () {
   if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
       cordova.plugins.Keyboard.show();
   }
}, 100);
```

Any help is appreciated, I want to show the keyboard right after entry in the input.