# keyboard doesn't open in ios on focus

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, browser, swiftui

I am currently developing the login aspect inside a custom browser on ios. I want to open the keyboard when a user clicks on an input element. When an input element gets clicked, I set the 'autofocus' attribute for that element, followed by a focus on the element. However, these steps are not sufficient for opening the keyboard.
I have tried methods present in the link: [IOS show keyboard on input focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54424729/ios-show-keyboard-on-input-focus), but nothing works.
The software version I'm working with is 14.4.2.

I am testing the app on an iPad.

```
var ev = new MouseEvent('click', {
                                       'view': window,
                                       'bubbles': true,
                                       'cancelable': true,
                                       'screenX': x,
                                       'screenY': y
                                   });

//x and y are the screen coordinates of the point where a user clicks.
var el = document.elementFromPoint(x, y); 
console.log("Clicked element: "+el); //print element to console
                                   
el.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    el.setAttribute('autofocus', 'autofocus');
                    el.focus();
});
el.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55652503/10654410) might be relevant to your situation.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55652503/10654410) might be relevant to your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmatic focus using element.focus() doesn't trigger the system-level keyboard to open because WKWebView only shows the keyboard if the focus is initiated by a user.
When the focus is triggered during user script evaluation, it is not considered as user interaction.

WebKit bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=243416

Changes done by Apple developers here: https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/pull/2907

The changes are still in beta mode and have not yet been rolled out to the latest iPad OS version.

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing your app in Simulator , make sure I/O -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard is unchecked. Otherwise, you won't see the keyboard appear.

Comment: Hi Marco, I'm testing the app on an iPad at the moment.