# IOS- Show keyboard on input focus

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, keyboard-events

I have an input box in react, I have passed the focus prop to make the input focused when someone lands on the component.

On Android, it works well, it focuses the input and pops up the keyboard.

On iOS, it does not work well, it focuses the input but does not shows the keyboard implicitly. I need to click on the input again to pops the keyboard.

I want that as soon as the user lands on the page, the keyboard shows up.

Here is the code: https://github.com/ritikbanger/react18-input-otp/blob/main/src/lib/index.jsx

Here is code sand box for the same: https://codesandbox.io/s/react18-input-otp-0nxzx7?file=/src/App.js

I have tried the following solutions but does not worked:

1. [IOS show keyboard on input focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54424729/ios-show-keyboard-on-input-focus)
2. [displaying keyboard in Safari iOS after focus on input after page loads (modal shows) in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72433442/displaying-keyboard-in-safari-ios-after-focus-on-input-after-page-loads-modal-s)
3. [How do I focus an HTML text field on an iPhone (causing the keyboard to come up)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979309/how-do-i-focus-an-html-text-field-on-an-iphone-causing-the-keyboard-to-come-up)
4. [show keyboard on input focus without user action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71826145/show-keyboard-on-input-focus-without-user-action)

Comment: where do you call focus command? can you call it with delay for testing? for example after render.

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar I have used it here- https://github.com/ritikbanger/react18-input-otp/blob/9245ec1579f251ed88a3c0f754e34c160e87eab7/src/lib/index.jsx#L30

Also, it is set after the componentDidMount is called i.e. after render

Comment: can you add a delay for focus just for testing? I want to make sure the issue is not for lifecycle.

Comment: Okay, let me try with a delay.

Comment: FYI, the input is focused already but the keyboard does not pops up on iOS.

Comment: Not working with delay @MaziarSaadatfar

Comment: If I recall correctly, iOS tries hard to thwart this as they feel it takes away control from the user... can't recall if there is a way to force the keyboard on this

Comment: @scunliffe That's why I am looking for a workaround