# How to force Mobile Keyboard to appear on html5 page without textbox?

Tags: javascript, android, ios

How to force mobile phone Keyboard to appear on web page without adding a textbox?

I have a canvas game that needs it to appear.

Comment: the question is solved in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609765/manually-triggering-the-iphone-ipad-ipod-keyboard-from-javascript

Comment: ok thanks, but I don't see any accepted answer there, will try those