# How to take input on a mobile site without a input field

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-website, keyup

The user needs to press the key X for the function to run and it works perfectly where there is a physical keyboard but how can I force a virtual keyboard on the mobile version? I can't think of a way to do this without adding an input field.

```js
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 88) {
   newx();
  }
});
function newx()
{alert("Hello");
}
```

```html
<h1>Key in X</h1>
```

The repl I'm using this for -> https://home.ajkallivayalil.repl.co/

Comment: Seems like a separate User Experience for mobile is ideal for this scenario (e.g., "Tap screen to Explore")

Answer (score 2):

After some searching on Google, I came up with this, but I suggest you make another user experience, as @[95faf8e76605e973](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8680805/95faf8e76605e973) said. (e.g. a button)

If you have some sort of input field and make it hidden, like using `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`, you can use JavaScript to activate it anytime, thus bringing up a keyboard.

To do this, you just have to use `.focus()` on your element.

[A link to the SO page I found.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609765/manually-triggering-the-iphone-ipad-ipod-keyboard-from-javascript)